# Solving an Involved Set of Coupled Differential Equations

Tags: python, ode

I am trying to solve a set of complicated differential equations in Python. These equations contain five functions (defined in the function 'ODEs' in the code below) that are functions of a variable n (greek name is eta--- I used n and eta interchangeably as variable names). These coupled differential equations contain a function (called a) which is a function of a parameter t. n (or eta) is also a function of t and so my first goal was to express, again numerically, the function a as a function of n (eta). Hence I had to solve a less involved pair of differential equations, which I defined in the function 'coupleODE'. I got a plot of a(t) and n(t) and used interpolation to get a model relating function a to function n. This function is a numerical estimation for a(n). I called this interpolation model 'f_quad' --- f, means function, and quad represents quadratic interpolation.

Now, the original five differential equations actually contain a'(n)/a(n), where ' is derivative with respect to n. I numerically found an interpolator for this as well and called it 'deriv_quad'.

Now in 'ODEs' I am modelling the five differential equations, and as you can see in the code, the function body contains segments that use the interpolators 'f_quad' and 'deriv_quad'; these have argument n, which represents the a(n) and a'(n) respectively. I then use odeint python function to numerically solve these differential equations, but I get the error message:

'A value in x_new is above the interpolation range.' My computer says that the error occurred in the line 'f = odeint(ODEs, initials, n_new, atol=1.0e-8, rtol=1.0e-6)'.

I am not sure why this happened; I used the same eta values that I used when finding the interpolators 'f_quad' and 'deriv_quad'. Can anyone help me get rid of this error?

Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.misc import derivative
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

def coupledODE(x,t):
    #define important constants
    m = 0.315
    r = 0.0000926
    d = 0.685
    H_0 = 67.4   

    a = x[0]
    eta = x[1]

    dndt = a**(-1)
    dadt = H_0 * (m*a**(-1) + r*a**(-2) + d*a**2)**(1/2)

    return [dadt, dndt]

#initial condtions
x0 = [1e-7, 1e-8]
t = np.linspace(0,0.01778301154,7500)  

x = odeint(coupledODE, x0, t, atol=1.0e-8, rtol=1.0e-6)  #vector of the functions a(t), n(t)


a = x[:,0]
n = x[:,1]  #Eta; n is the greek letter eta


plt.semilogx(t,a)
plt.xlabel('time')
plt.ylabel('a(t)')
plt.show()

plt.semilogx(t,n)
plt.xlabel('time')
plt.ylabel('Eta')
plt.show()

plt.plot(n,a)
plt.xlabel('Eta')
plt.ylabel('a(t)')
plt.show()


##############################################################################
# Calculate the Derivative a' (i.e. da/d(eta) Numerically 
##############################################################################
derivative_values = []

for i in range(7499):
    numerator = x[i+1,0] - x[i,0]
    denominator = x[i+1,1] - x[i,1]
    ratio = numerator / denominator
    derivative_values.append(ratio)


x_axis = n
x_axis = np.delete(x_axis, -1)

plt.plot(x_axis,derivative_values)
plt.xlabel('Eta')
plt.ylabel('Derivative of a')
plt.show()

##############################################################################
#Interpolation
##############################################################################

#Using quadratic interpolation

f_quad = interp1d(n, a, kind = 'quadratic')
deriv_quad = interp1d(x_axis, derivative_values, kind = 'quadratic')

n_new = np.linspace(1.0e-8, 0.0504473, num = 20000, endpoint = True)

plt.plot(n_new, f_quad(n_new))

plt.xlabel('Eta')
plt.ylabel('a')
plt.show()

plt.plot(n_new, deriv_quad(n_new))

plt.xlabel('Eta')
plt.ylabel('Derivative of a')
plt.show()

#print(x[0,1])
#print(eta_new[0])
#print(deriv_quad(1e-8))

##############################################################################
# The Main Coupled Equations
##############################################################################
def ODEs(x,n):
    fourPiG_3 = 1  
    CDM_0 = 1      
    Rad_0 = 1      
    k = 0.005      

    Phi = x[0]
    Theta1 = x[1]
    iSpeed = x[2]
    DeltaC = x[3]
    Theta0 = x[4]

    dPhi_dn = fourPiG_3 *((CDM_0 * DeltaC)/ deriv_quad(n) + (4*Rad_0)/(f_quad(n)*deriv_quad(n))) - 
    (k**2*Phi*f_quad(n))/(deriv_quad(n)) - (deriv_quad(n) * Phi)/(f_quad(n))
    dTheta1_dn = (k/3)*(Theta0 - Phi)
    diSpeed_dn = -k*Phi - (deriv_quad(n)/f_quad(n))*iSpeed
    dDeltaC_dn = -k*iSpeed - 3*dPhi_dn
    dTheta0_dn = -k*Theta1 - dPhi_dn

    return [dPhi_dn, dTheta1_dn, diSpeed_dn, dDeltaC_dn, dTheta0_dn]




hub_0 = deriv_quad(1e-8)/f_quad(1e-8)
#Now the initial conditions
Phi_k_0 = 1.0e-5
Theta1_k_0 = -1*Phi_k_0/hub_0  #Ask about the k
iSpeed_k_0 = 3*Theta1_k_0
DeltaC_k_0 = 1.5 * Phi_k_0
Theta0_k_0 = 0.5 * Phi_k_0

initials = [Phi_k_0, Theta1_k_0, iSpeed_k_0, DeltaC_k_0, Theta0_k_0]

####Error Happens Here ####
f = odeint(ODEs, initials, n_new, atol=1.0e-8, rtol=1.0e-6)

Phi = f[:,0]
Theta1 = f[:,1]
iSpeed = f[:,2]
DeltaC = f[:,3]
Theta0 = f[:,4]
```

Comment: Simple, you evaluate an interpolation with `deriv_quad` inside your `ODEs` function. During the integration, the value that is given where the interpolation should be made is outside the domain of definition of the interpolated data. You can try and increase this domain, or use extrapolation.

Comment: @Laurent90 Thanks